# Developing app to detect webpage change

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a desktop app with java to track changes made to a webpage as a side project and also to monitor when my professors add content to their webpages. I did a bit of research and my current approach is to use the Jsoup library to retrieve the webpage, run it through a hashing algorithm, and then compare the current hash value with a previous hash value.

Is this a recommended approach? I'm open to suggestions and ideas since before I did any research I had no clue how to start nor what jsoup was.

Comment: You seem to be confusing getting HTML with parsing HTML. You're not parsing HTML, so why did you think you needed an HTML parser?

Comment: I wanted to parse HTML because I was planning to display the changes that were made for quick and easy viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential problem with your hashing method: if the page contains any dynamically generated content that changes on each refresh, as many modern websites do, your program will report that the page is constantly changing. Hashing the whole page will only work if the site does not employ any of this dynamic content (ads, hit counter, social media, etc.).

What specifically are you looking for that has changed? Perhaps new assignments being posted? You likely do not want to monitor the entire page for changes anyway. Therefore, you should use an **HTML parser** -- this is where Jsoup comes in.

First, **parse** the page into a Document object:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString)
```

You can now perform a number of methods on the Document object to **traverse the HTML Nodes**. [(See Jsoup docs on DOM navigation methods)](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

For instance, say there is a table on the site, and each row of the table represents a different assignment. The following code would get the table by its ID and each of its row by selecting each of the table's tags.

```
Element assignTbl = doc.getElementById("assignmentTable");
Elements tblRows = assignTbl.getElementsByTag("tr");
for (Element tblRow: tblRows) {
    tblRow.html();
}
```

You will need to somehow view the webpage's source code (such as Inspect Element in Google Chrome) to figure out the page's structure and design your code accordingly. This way, not only would the algorithm be more reliable, but you could take it much further, such as extracting the details of the assignment that has changed. (If you would like assistance, please edit your question with the target page's HTML.)

Comment: The websites are static, and I'm mostly interested in seeing whether assignments or lecture notes have been added. If I wanted to determine what was added and display it with a GUI for quick viewing/downloading, would I have to keep a copy of an older version of the page/section for comparison? If I were to keep a copy then I don't see any reason to be hashing the content and then comparing.

Comment: True; you could completely get rid of hashing if you keep a cached copy-- for example, an array of the HTML strings of the assignments. Hashing is technically more efficient but is unnecessary for small amounts of data.